# SMTP defer vs reject

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

When should I use `defer` and when `reject`?

In my case there is postfix running. The parameter [smtpd_relay_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_restrictions) defaults to `defer_unauth_destination`, while the [Access Readme](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html) suggests `reject_unauth_destination`.

Answer (score 9):

It is failsafe feature from postfix. Imagine that you just have postfix installed and then point your MX record of example.com to postfix **before** you include example.com to your postfix configuration. If the default parameter is `reject_unauth_destination`, all email going to example.com will be permanently rejected.

In short, change the default configuration `defer_unauth_destination` to `reject_unauth_destination` when you are sure that all domains belongs to your postfix has been included to the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Postfix and generally all mailservers defer temporary failures. Temporary failures have `4.x.x` code. There are permanent failures that have `5.x.x` code. Mailservers don't retry permanent failures by default.

Access readme suggests that for a reason. If unauth_destination failure happens it probably will happen if you retry, It's more like a permanent failure that won't go away on it's own over time.